# Scope is not working with interactive user login azure ad b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, aad-b2c

I am trying to use the scripts in https://github.com/cljung/AzureAD-B2C-scripts and trying to do the below connecting device login with Scope to avoid client credentials.

`Connect-AzADB2CDevicelogin -TenantName "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" -Scope "Application.Read.All Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"`

I am getting the below error:

> AADSTS65002: Consent between first-party application '1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2' and first party resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' must be configured via preauthorization - applications owned and operated by Microsoft must get approval from the API owner before requesting tokens for that API.

Could you please help me with what can be the issue and how can I get the approval?

Comment: https://github.com/cljung/AzureAD-B2C-scripts#3-grant-permissions-to-b2c-graph-app

Comment: Thank you for your response @JasSuri-MSFT.
But I was trying to avoid using graph-app-> client credentials and trying to use the interactive user login to the operations on the b2c tenant, as mentioned in https://github.com/cljung/AzureAD-B2C-scripts#start-a-powershell-session-for-you-b2c-tenant 
If you don't like the concept of working with client credentials, you can use the device login method and use you interactive user. In order to be able to upload your B2C Custom Policies, you would need to specify the correct scopes,

Comment: Create a new application registration. Give it delegated permissions to the scopes you require for MS Graph API. Then pass in the clientId as a parameter into the command you are running for device login `Connect-AzADB2CDevicelogin -TenantName "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" -Scope "Directory.ReadWrite.All" -ClientId "yourNewClientId`

Comment: Yes, I tried but below is the error I am getting, I also tried adding client_secret in the json body but it didn't work
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: f957b469-32aa-4c58-ad89-94b79ff74800\r\nCorrelation ID:
bb45b94a-6d6e-487a-aaba-6ebe599880df\r\nTimestamp: 2022-01-26 09:57:44Z",

Comment: It worked, I missed allowing the client flow in the application, thank you for your inputs @JasSuri-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

The general idea here is that an application cannot randomly read information in/from another tenant without an administrator consenting to that. That's where the consent framework comes into play:

> The Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) consent framework makes it easy to develop multi-tenant web and native client applications. These applications allow sign-in by user accounts from an Azure AD tenant that's different from the one where the application is registered. They may also need to access web APIs such as the Microsoft Graph API (to access Azure AD, Intune, and services in Microsoft 365) and other Microsoft services' APIs, in addition to your own web APIs.
>
> The framework is based on a user or an administrator giving consent to an application that asks to be registered in their directory, which may involve accessing directory data. For example, if a web client application needs to read calendar information about the user from Microsoft 365, that user is required to consent to the client application first. After consent is given, the client application will be able to call the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the user, and use the calendar information as needed.

Read up on the [Azure Active Directory consent framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework) and find out how to implement it in the correct way for your scenario.

**EDIT:**
According to [Azure AD Authentication and authorization error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes):

> A developer in your tenant may be attempting to reuse an App ID owned by Microsoft. This error prevents them from impersonating a Microsoft application to call other APIs. They must move to another app ID they register in https://portal.azure.com.

Looks like there's some misconfiguration.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @rickvdbosch, the application I am trying to connect is a Microsoft owned application to authenticate the Microsoft PowerShell, Can it be possible to create a new application and grant consent as Powershell client Id, please suggest,